# Formatting MultiBinding TimeSpan to hide milliseconds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, timespan, multibinding

I'm currently trying to multibind a WPF TextBlock to a TimeSpan property.

The following works:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Text="{Binding Path=ImportOperationRuntime, StringFormat='hh\\:mm\\:ss'}" />
```

Unfortunately, using a MultiBinding "destroys" the StringFormat and displays the milliseconds alongside (though hidden through the StringFormat). The following ones do not work:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Total runtime: {0}">
            <Binding Path="ImportOperationRuntime" StringFormat="hh':'mm':'ss" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Total runtime: {0}">
            <Binding Path="ImportOperationRuntime" StringFormat="hh\:mm\:ss" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Total runtime: {0}">
            <Binding Path="ImportOperationRuntime" StringFormat="hh\\:mm\\:ss" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Total runtime: {0}">
            <Binding Path="ImportOperationRuntime" StringFormat="hh:mm:ss" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

And the very same StringFormats when used in the actual MultiBinding do not work (ex: `<MultiBinding StringFormat="Total runtime: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}">`).

How should I structure my StringFormat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Total runtime: {0:hh\:mm\:ss}">
    <Binding Path="ImportOperationRuntime"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Normally in code behind you use a double backslash `\\` for escaping.
This is not the case in xaml. One is enough.

Comment: This is it, but, @SeToY, did you tried using the Binding tool from VS? It places the escape chars perfectly.

Comment: @Tico First time I'm hearing about a VS Binding Tool :D

Comment: In the Property tab, click the little square left to the property, there's an option for creating Binding, you can format there.