# Formatting a bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to bind `Value` of a Slider to a `Content` of a Label. The value of the slider sets a timespan. The value of the slider is a timespan in minutes (value 5 = 5 minutes).

This is my XAML for the Label:

```
<Label
  Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=sld_Timespan}"
  ContentStringFormat="{}{0:HH:mm}"
/>
```

I can bind them. The values are correct. But the format is wrong.

For `ContentStringFormat` i tried different settings, like on [this (TextBlock in Silverlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584948/format-date-time-in-xaml-in-silverlight) or [this (TextBlock Multibinding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576270/formatting-multibinding-timespan-to-hide-milliseconds) site. I also took the data binding dialog and set the StringFormat to {0:G} (you can choose this from a ComboBox) or other settings.

I only get a value "formatted" as double, like "1" or "13.423523423".

I also tried TextBlock. The same problem.

What is wrong with my XAML code?

Comment: You might need a value converter for that. What is the received error?

Comment: @Samuel I do not receive an error. I checked it out: i can type everything, i do not get any error. It seems that Visual Studio is hiding formatting errors.

Comment: Did you check the output tab of visual studio? It may contain some information about binding issues, etc.

Comment: @fedab `Value` of the `Slider` of a `double` type. Bind `Label.Content` to `TimeSpan` property

Comment: @Samuel No, there is only some information about missing summaries and in debug about skipped loading symbols and not loaded symbols (and debug exited with 0 (0x0)).

Comment: As dkozl said, the `Value` property is of type double and will therefore not be formatted as TimeSpan by a ContentStringFormat. Either bind `Content` to a view model property of type TimeSpan, or use a binding converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment of Clemens i understood what was wrong. I wrote a simple Converter:

```
public class DoubleToTimespanConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)value).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And added to my XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--local is my local namespace-->
    <local:DoubleToTimespanConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And i could easily set "converter" as my converter.

Comment: You might prefer to write `TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)value)`, which is much easier to understand if you happen to look at this later.